# JSON produced by Ruby not compatible with JavaScript's JSON parser

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I am running into an issue where the JSON produced by a Ruby script is not compatible when parsed by JavaScripts `JSON.parse`. Consider the following example:

```
# Ruby
require 'json'
hash = {}
hash["key"] = "value with \u001a unicode"
hash.to_json
=> '{"key":"value with \u001a unicode"}'

// JavaScript
JSON.parse('{"key":"value with \u001a unicode"}')
=> JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

The issue is the unicode character `\u001a`. The solution to this is to escape `\u001a` to `\\u001a`, but the thing is, the `\u001a` is automatically inserted into the string by Ruby. I can't reliably post-process the result. Any ideas about how to solve this?

Please note that I wish to call `JSON.parse` inside a JavaScript execution environment, not inside Ruby's interpreter.

Comment: I ran your code and I'm actually getting this as output: `=> "{\"key\":\"value with \\u001a unicode\"}"`

Comment: I ran your code also and it worked fine.

Comment: You are looking at the output in the terminal. `\\u001a` is the terminal is the physical string `\u001a`. Ruby displays the backslash as \\ so you can tell the difference between the single character `\u001a` and the six character string also written `\u001a`.

Comment: Also note that `JSON.parse` should be called inside a JavaScript execution environment, not inside the Ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version is that you're interpreting your string as a Javascript expression before attempting to decode it as JSON.

U+001A is a control character. [RFC 4627 explicitly disallows control characters U+0000-U+001F in quoted strings](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Your problem here is not the the JSON is invalid, but that you are unescaping your control characters before attempting to parse them as JSON.

When you dump the string `"\u001a"` from Ruby and copy and paste it into a Javascript interpreter, the escape sequence translates to an unescaped control character, which is not a valid character in JSON! Non-prohibited characters work just fine - you can happily `JSON.parse('["\u0020"]')`, for example.

However, if you *don't* interpret the string as Javascript, and instead read it as raw bytes, it will parse correctly.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> open("out.json", "w") {|f| f.print JSON.dump(["\u001a"]) }
=> nil

$ node -e 'require("fs").readFile("out.json", function(err, data) { console.log(JSON.parse(data)); });'
[ '\u001a' ]
```

If you're going to be copy-pasting, you need to be copying an *escaped* version of the string, so that when the string is parsed by your Javascript engine, the escape double-escaped sequences properly unescape to escape sequences rather than characters. So, rather than copying the output of `JSON.dump(["\u001a"])`, you should be copying the output of `puts JSON.dump(["\u001a"]).inspect`, which will correctly escape any escape sequences in the string.

Comment: Is there a way to write out the properly escaped version of the string? I'm writing the string out to a file and then someone else is reading the file in and copying the string into a JavaScript file (programmatically).

Comment: If you're writing it out with Javascript, `JSON.stringify(json_string)`. If you're writing it with Ruby, `JSON.dump(json_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

To me following ruby code gives `"{\"key\":\"value with \\u001a unicode\"}"`
 in output.

And `JSON.parse` also abel to pass it. and gives `Object {key: "value with  unicode"}`.

Comment: You're looking at the code in the terminal. It escapes the display String so you can see the characters. Otherwise, how could you tell the difference between `\\u001a` and `\u001a`. So `\\u001a` is the literal string `\u001a` without unicode escaping. To see the difference, compare the results of `"\\u001a".size` and `"\u001a".size`. Notice that the length of `\\u001a` is 6 *not* 7, meaning that Ruby is displaying the `\` escaped.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> JSON text is encoded in unicode. The default unicode is utf-8.

I ran your code in irb and got the following:

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > require 'json'
 => true
1.9.3-p484 :002 >
1.9.3-p484 :003 >   hash = {}
 => {}
1.9.3-p484 :004 > hash["key"] = "value with \u001a unicode"
 => "value with \u001A unicode"
1.9.3-p484 :005 > hash.to_json
 => "{\"key\":\"value with \\u001a unicode\"}"
```

Then running the returned string in a javascript console, I get the following:

```
> JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"value with \\u001a unicode\"}")
> Object {key: "value with  unicode"}
```

It is returning an object. To get the value with unicode, you have to access the hash by calling:

```
> str = JSON.parse("{\"key\":\"value with \\u001a unicode\"}")
> Object {key: "value with  unicode"}
> str.key
> "value with  unicode"
```

Comment: JSON.parse should be executed in JavaScript execution environment, not inside Ruby's interpreter.

Comment: @Max actually, that works too. Just [copy-pasted it into Chrome's console](http://i.imgur.com/EDIDkUF.png). Those are even different languages!.. Whatever.

Comment: @D-side take a look at the accepted answer if you'd like an explanation of why Ruby's console output works. The console output is not the exact string returned by the `to_json` call.

Comment: @Max I actually know. I've hit a similar issue before when escaping shell commands in Ruby. The general rule here is: know when and how many times your input will be unescaped.